# Static list in a class listing methods

Tags: python-3.x

I want to have a class attribute in python which is simply a list of methods of the class, so that I can iterate over it for testing purposes.

However, I am not sure how to get the desired behavior.

So far what I have is:

```
class MyClass:
    methods = [MyClass.method1, myClass.method2]
```

Which gives me undefined name error.

How do I get what I want?

Comment: The class name is not in scope inside the definition, and the methods aren't available until defined; put `methods = [method1, ...]` at the end of the class.

Comment: you will have to define the attributes first, do something like this in the class definition: `def method1(self): self.attr1 = 'Anythingyouwant'`